# GO Error writing xml struct to file

Tags: xml, struct, go

Currently my console output is formatted like `[{a} {b} {c} {d}]`.

I'm looking to write this output to a file in place of `fmt.Println(a)`, but every time I am met with an error such as:

```
cannot use a (type []Group) as type []byte in argument to ioutil.WriteFile' or similar
cannot use a (`type []Group`) as type `io.Writer` in argument to `fmt.Fprint`:
[]Group does not implement io.Writer (missing Write method)).
```

Do I need to convert `[]group` to another type?  I have tried `json.Marshall(group)` but that ended up the same.

```
package main

import (
  "fmt"
  "net/http"
  "io/ioutil"
  "encoding/xml"
)

type Bedework struct {
  XMLName xml.Name `xml:"bedework"`
  Groups []Group `xml:"groups>group"`
}

type Group struct {
  Name string `xml:"name"`
}

func main() {
  response, err := http.Get("http://localhost:3000/cal/?noxslt=yes")
  if err != nil {
    fmt.Println("Error opening file:", err)
    return
  } else {
    defer response.Body.Close()

    contents, _ := ioutil.ReadAll(response.Body)

    var b Bedework
    var g []Group
    xml.Unmarshal(contents, &b)
    for _, group := range b.Groups {
        g = append(g, group)
    }
  fmt.Println(g)
  }
}
```

Comment: Use [`fmt.Fprintln()`](https://golang.org/pkg/fmt/#Fprintln) like this `err, fd := os.OpenFile("myfile.txt", os.O_WRONLY|os.O_TRUNC, 0666); fmt.Fprintln(fd, g); fd.Close()` ?

Comment: But I don't quite get your question: it's titled like having to do something with XML, your code example does something with XML but then you basically ask about how would you use `fmt.Println()` to write to a file rather than to a console.  Could you narrow your question down as much as possible? If you want to write `g` to a file, XML is completely irrelevant. If you want to write XML, everything else is completely irrelevant. Please read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: ...and you didn't even show us the code which fails for you.

Comment: I took what you gave me and changed it slightly and it ended up working, thank you!  About the XML - Sorry, new to GO and my Bedework struct was dealing with pulling XML and putting it in to []Group but I realize now I did not word the title correctly.  If you want to put up what you wrote in your first comment as the answer I can select it.

Comment: What was the point of editing your question to put the answer in it? It sort of defeats the original purpose of the question.

Comment: Put it back to how it was.

Comment: @Noahhh Well it's good you got it working! You are supposed to provide an answer below, and then click on the "accept" button. Before you do that the question shows up in the "unanswered" queue.